# Reject User input if Input is Less than Total Amount

Tags: c#

Good day, I checked all the existing code to find a way through this but since i am a new one, i can't solve it without a guide.

On this code, it only accept integers but i want to prevent the user to accept input if input is less than computed total amount

For example, User input is 5 and total amount is 10, the program will still accept that and that's an error,

So where will i put if Amountended < TotalAmount then loop again

```
bool test3 = false;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(67, 19);
                Console.Write(" ");

                Console.SetCursorPosition(67, 19);
                AmountTended = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                test3 = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                test3 = true;
            }
        } while (test3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting

```
if (AmountTended < TotalAmount)
{
    test3 = true;
}
```

in the 'try' code block, after

```
test3 = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking for user input and setting `test3` to `false` regardless of the value entered by user. So your loops ends after user enters a valid value.

Instead you need to perform an actual check:

```
decimal value = 0.0m;
while(value < TotalAmount)
{
   value = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

This loop will continue as long as the value entered by user is less than the `TotalAmount`.

**Note:** In order to handle invalid inputs you can try using `decimal.TryParse` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and see this one out